# Permission dialog when installing android app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, permissions, location, android-install-apk

I'm developing an Android game using Unity3d.
When i generate the .apk file using Unity and then install the application on my phone, in the installation dialog it says that the "apllication does not require any special permissions". However, in my android manifest i have Internet and Location permissions.

As far as i understand if the targetSdk > 23, the internet permission is perceived as a normal permission and so it does not prompt a permission dialog. However, as soon as i start the application it asks for access to the device location. This is all fine by me, and i figure it is the way it is supposed to work.

My question is this: Why does the installation dialog state that the application does not require any special permissions? Shouldn't, atleast the Location permission, be stated in the installation dialog?

My manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.DiogoMelo.Exergame" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:isGame="true" android:banner="@drawable/app_banner">
    <activity android:name="com.yusufolokoba.pedometer.PedometerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density">
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="unity.build-id" android:value="fe7aacd9-9aed-4446-a3d2-45a1f1474bda" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="0" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-enable" android:value="True" />
    <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: But Location permission `!=` Internet permission. Location permission requires that you also request it at run time too

Comment: And it requests when i open the application.
But is it right that the installation dialog says "no special permissions"?

Comment: I can't answer that because you did not show what your Manifest looks like. The answer to that is only possible when I see the Manifest.

Comment: I just edited my question and posted my manifest. Thank you

Comment: The answer to the question in your second comment is no. "INTERNET" is a normal permission and "no special permissions" is correct here but once "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" is added, that message comes incorrect. Is this the first time you opened the app? Did you re-install the app?

Comment: The first time i open the app it asks for Location access, if i decline, once i open the app again it asks again.
As far as re-installing, i've done it a few times but the result is always the same. "No special permissions needed" upon installation and then it asks for Location access when it is opened.

Comment: I believe you see the *"No special permissions needed"* because you have installed the app before. I may be wrong but can you change the package name, build and install the app and see if you still get that message on the first run?

Comment: I just tried it on a different phone for the first time and it says the exact same thing.

However after more research i've found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504240/android-app-doesnt-require-any-special-access/41506946) which leads me to believe that this is what is supposed to happen.

Comment: Ya but that message is misleading to the people that will download the app. It doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the permissions were changed severely in android sdk 23, before all permissions had to be granted at installation time. Since 23, the permissions only get requested at runtime, ideally only when required. With Unity I think the permissions always directly get asked on first start to make things easier.

Comment: So, no matter what permissions i require, the installation dialog will always say that the application does not require special permissions? Even though it asks the user for permission when the application is started?

Comment: Yes because at that stage (installation time) it does not require them. According to Android guidelines you would then only ask the user for permission when you really require it lets say for location feature X of your app. The user app does not require the permission as long as the user does not need feature X of your app. Of course this logic makes less sense when the permissions get asked for at app start, but that is not the intended way. With unity I think it is the normal way though.

Answer (score 0):

I finally had the time to test on a phone running Android 5.1 and the installation dialog shows the permissions needed. So there is no problem, it just depends on the android version runnning.